# What is wrong with my login validation code? I;m using Java Swing & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am a beginner and I just began writing my first real GUI project. I intend to create a simple school management system and I just finished creating the signup and login screens.
The signup page works fine, it adds user details to the mySQL database seamlessly. The problem is I can't get the login page to validate the details correctly. Each time I enter a correct password/username it displays the failure message. Which is what it should do when the details are wrong. 
I have 2 classes, the main class holds the login page code, and the second class deals with the connection to the DB and also defines the methods for Login which are then called in the main class.
Here's my code. Please help out. Thank you.

`
//VALIDATE LOGIN

```
public Boolean checkLogin (String username, String password) {

    //SQL STATEMENT
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM `school_management_system`.`login_details` WHERE `username`=? and `password`=?";

    try {
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school_management_system","root","mathenge24");
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        System.out.println("Conected successfully");

        //PREPARED STATEMENT
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);

        //EXECUTE PREPARED STATEMENT
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {

            //Returns true if the query finds any corresponding data
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    } catch(SQLException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
`
```

Here is the action perfomed code for the login button:

```
private void loginbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //String temp_pwd = passwordtxt.getText();

    //Call checklogin() to authenticate details
    DBconnect db = new DBconnect();

    if(db.checkLogin(usernametxt.getName(), passwordtxt.getText())) {

        //POP UP MESSAGE
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have logged in succesfully", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }
    else {
        //popup box
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed!", "Failed!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any exception has been thrown in console ? Also did you stored your password in encrypted format and forgot to the same while loging ?

Comment: could be issue with your query.. print the result you receive from db after you execute the prepared statement and validate if the query is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In loginbtnActionPerformed you call tje verification with

```
(usernametxt.getName(
```

You would'nt want the component's name, do you?

```
 usernametext.getText ()
```

Will work better :-)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm :-) Beginner mistakes I guess.

Comment: Of course. Couldn't upvote the answer as useful though, they say I have to earn a total of 15 reputations. I only have 3 lol. I appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't have any exceptions i guess your result set has the size of zero...

validate simply by using this code:

```
try {
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/school_management_system","root","mathenge24");
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    System.out.println("Conected successfully");

    //PREPARED STATEMENT
    pst.setString(1, username);
    pst.setString(2, password);

    //EXECUTE PREPARED STATEMENT
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    return true;
} catch(SQLException exc) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That code would allow accounts to login with invalid username/password

Comment: sorry, you have not read the specs @Jan : invalid credentials would throw an exception, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29

Comment: nevermind @Jan your answer has been accepted, it's not a match, keep up the good work...

Comment: Username and passwords were Parameters here, not db credentials.

Comment: Thanks too Martin, though Jan's code worked perfectly. I do appreciate the fact that you took the time to answer my question. Cheers :-)

Comment: thanks Mathenge, im glad @Jan could help you out ^_^ good luck with your school project!!